# 2D Grid in Code-First Entity Framework: How to set the primary keys for fast look-up based on X and Y?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, geometry, database-performance

If I wanted to store a table of tiles where no tiles can have the same X and Y value (each has a unique location) would it be better to make the primary key a string like "4,-20" (this seems like the wrong answer) or to use a standard increment primary key ID and just store X and Y as other columns?

Alternatively, could I make X and Y BOTH the primary keys? Then I would not need to store some kind of combined string to make sure they are unique... or would I? Make some kind of dual constraint?

Basically I want it to be fast to look-up a row based on X and Y or even a range of X and Y values.

```
public class Tile
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this with DB-First or Code-First? (But short answer, yes. Composite Primary Keys should be the way to go. The database will ensure uniqueness based on the combination of all the fields defined as Primary Key)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a composite primary key for this to work. A primary key guarantees that every value is unique, and when this is applied to multiple columns, it makes sure that each *pair* is unique.

For creating with Code-First: ([this blog post used as reference](http://www.luisrocha.net/2010/11/creating-composite-keys-using-code.html))

```cs
public class Tile
{
    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int X { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=2)]
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public string AdditionalField1 { get ;set; }
}
```

For creating with DB-First (which I always prefer)

```sql
create table Tile
(
    [X] int not null,
    [Y] int not null,
    AdditionalField1 nvarchar(max) null,

    constraint PK_Tile primary key ([X], [Y])
);
```